# LAravel composer View dependency doesn't see

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I have error like this:

```
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $products ]] in class App\Http\ViewComposers\ShoppingCartComposer
```

I want to send my data from CartController to ViewComposer ( here $products) but my dependency doesn't see it.

My Code is :
View composer :

```
namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

 use Illuminate\View\View;

class ShoppingCartComposer
{

protected $products;


public function __construct(Array $products)
{
    // Dependencies automatically resolved by service container...
    $this->products = $products;
}

public function countProducts(){

}

public function compose(View $view)
{
    $view->with('count', 'test');
}
}
```

Here is Composer service provider:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

public function boot()
{

    View::composer(
        'shopping-cart', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\ShoppingCartComposer'
    );

}

public function register()
{

}
```

}

And here is cart Conrtoller from where I wany to send &products from index controller:

```
class CartController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    if (Session::has('shoppingCart')) {
        $products = Session::get('shoppingCart');
    } else {
        $products = [];
    }

    return view('shopping-cart', ['products' => $products]);
}
```

Comment: try this link https://scotch.io/amp/tutorials/sharing-data-between-views-using-laravel-view-composers

Comment: I wriote this but still don's solve my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Its not finding the variable `$products` because you need to pass it to the compose method in your view composer:

```
public function compose(View $view)
{
    $view->with([
        "products" => $this->products,
        "test" => "TEST"
    ]);
}
```

Hope this helps you.